# Need help solving equation involving $\cosh$

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

I am trying to solve this equation for $a$

$$R= (a)\cosh\left(\frac{l}{a}\right)$$

where $R$ and $l$ are real positive constants.

I tried breaking $\cosh$ into exponentials but this didnt seem to help.

Comment: Are you multiplying $cosh$ by $a$, or is that the arc-hyperbolic-cosine function?

Comment: @vadim123: Given the title I assumed it was $a$ multiplied by $\cosh$ but you're right it could have been notation for $\operatorname{arccosh}$.

Comment: yes it is a times the hyperbolic function. what would be the best notation to make this clear?

Comment: Best notation would be to change $a$ to a different letter. :-)

Comment: The parentheses in the current version of the question make it quite clear.  I am a big fan of parentheses.

Comment: One of the Programmer Rule: "In case of dude, use parentheses". I'm addict too.

Comment: Solve numerically $\displaystyle{\large \mu x - \cosh\left(x\right) = 0}$ with $\displaystyle{\large \mu \equiv {R \over l}}$. Then, $\displaystyle{\large a = {l \over x}}$

Comment: For future readers: there is likely a Mellin Barnes type integral representation, with a Bessel function, of the inverse function. However we cannot have this answer are many already posted.

Answer (score 1):

You might look at the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W_function)  It is basically the only tool we have for things that combine polynomials and exponentials.  Whether you consider a solution in terms of that acceptable is a matter of taste.  Many people don't accept it.  I didn't look whether I could solve this in terms of W.   We could define a function $M(R)$ that gives the answer you want, but that wouldn't help much.  A numerical solution is probably what you are in for.

Comment: Actually there isn't a closed-form expression for this one in terms of $W$, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is a bit of scaling that can be done to remove one parameter: if $t = a/\ell$ and $r = R/\ell$, the equation becomes $r  = t \cosh(1/t)$.
Now, besides numerical methods, you might try a series solution (for one of the two  branches of the solution): for large $r$,
$$ t = r- \dfrac{1}{2! r}-\dfrac{7}{4! r^3}-\dfrac{241}{6! r^5}-\dfrac{19279}{8! r^7} + \ldots $$

Comment: Using Lambert for the first estimate gives almost the solution after one single iteration of any Newton-like method.

Answer (score 0):

$\large\mbox{Hints}:$

1. $\displaystyle{%
   \mbox{Define}\ \mu \equiv {R \over \ell}\,,
   \quad
   x \equiv {\ell\ {\rm sgn}\left(\mu\right) \over a}.\
   \mbox{Then,}\quad \left\vert\mu\right\vert\, x = \cosh\left(x\right) 
   }$.
2. $\displaystyle{%
   \mbox{The solutions satisfy}\ x > {1 \over \left\vert\mu\right\vert}  
   }$.
3. There is $\it one$ solution $\left(~x_{t}~\right)$ which is valid for a particular valor $\mu_{t}$ of $\mu$. $x_{t}$ and $\mu_{t}$ are determined by the pair of equations
   $$
   \left.%
   \begin{array}{rcl}
   \cosh\left(x_{t}\right) & = & \left\vert\mu_{t}\right\vert\, x_{t}
   \\[1mm]
   \sinh\left(x_{t}\right) & = & \left\vert\mu_{t}\right\vert
   \end{array}\right\}
   \quad\mbox{which yield}\quad
   \left\{%
   \begin{array}{rcl}
   \left\vert\mu_{t}\right\vert
   & = &
   \sinh\left(\sqrt{1 + {1 \over \mu_{t}^{2}}\,}\,\right)
   \\[1mm]
   x_{t} & = & \sqrt{1 + {1 \over \mu_{t}^{2}}\,}
   \end{array}\right.
   $$
4. When $\left\vert\mu\right\vert < \left\vert\mu_{t}\right\vert$, there is not any real solution.
5. When $\left\vert\mu\right\vert > \left\vert\mu_{t}\right\vert$, we have $\it two$ solutions $\left(~x_{< \atop >}~\right)$:
   $$
   {1 \over \left\vert\mu\right\vert} <\ x_{<}\ <\ x_{t}\,,
   \qquad\qquad
   x_{>}\ >\ x_{t}
   $$
6. When $\left\vert\mu\right\vert \gg 1,\quad$
   $\displaystyle{%
   x_{<} \approx {1 \over \left\vert\mu\right\vert}
   +
   {1 \over \left\vert\mu\right\vert^{3}}
   }$

At least, the reader can take from here toward a
$\it\mbox{numerical calculation}$.

Answer (score 0):

*Almost ten years too late !*

Continuing the expansion given in @Robert Israel and transforming it as a Padé approximant of low degrees
$$t=r+\frac{60 \left(11303-9954 r^2\right) r}{60 \left(19908 r^2-34219\right) r^2+398027}+O\left(\frac{1}{r^9}\right)$$

Concerning the left branch of the curve, as @Ross Millikan wrote, we can take advantage of Lambert function since,if $t$ is small, then
$$r(t)=t \cosh \left(\frac{1}{t}\right) \sim \frac{1}{2} te^{\frac{1}{t}}$$ from which
$$r(t)=\frac{1}{2} te^{\frac{1}{t}}\implies t_0=-\frac{1}{W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{2 r(t)}\right)}$$ Now, using **one** single iteration of Halley method
gives extremely good results

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
r & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 10 & \color{red}{0.2222421500725}861711913621 &
                  0.2222421500725973096761854 \\
 20 & \color{red}{0.1862331343297978}293505787 & 
                  0.1862331343297978675828843 \\
 30 & \color{red}{0.1705612198514985}297213084 & 
                  0.1705612198514985313258937 \\
 40 & \color{red}{0.161086762368383517}3629720 &
                  0.1610867623683835175403648 \\
 50 & \color{red}{0.1544933072614891940}642392 &
                  0.1544933072614891940971162 \\
 60 & \color{red}{0.1495266555608954227}465585 & 
                  0.1495266555608954227549607 \\
 70 & \color{red}{0.14559003584384098636}28814 & 
                  0.1455900358438409863655546 \\
 80 &\color{red}{ 0.14235706580617812806}55875 & 
                  0.1423570658061781280665845 \\
 90 &\color{red}{ 0.1396315693952796847}498242 & 
                  0.1396315693952796847502436 \\
 100 & \color{red}{0.137287269123803503467}7868 & 
                   0.1372872691238035034679807
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using Householder method would significantly improve.